# How to add the Resource Servers of an UserPool using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

Using CloudFormation, how can I create Resource Servers for an UserPool in AWS Cognito?

In CloudFormation documentation, there are only 5 items under Cognito and I can't see how to configure a ResourceServer, is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. I couldn't find anything either. I suggest to create a support ticket and ask for that in case they don't have that on their roadmap already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible directly on cloudformation with `AWS::Cognito::UserPoolResourceServer` resource type. You don't need to create custom resources to create resource server. Now it is supported by cloudformation. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpoolresourceserver.html
I tried to update my custom resources to the cloudformation ones but for some reason, Resource servers are not updatable. So first I had to delete custom resources in one changeset and recreate as `AWS::Cognito::UserPoolResourceServer`.

Answer (score 1):

Resource Servers, among other items, are not supported by CloudFormation. This is a list of all [supported resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-supported-resources.html).

As an alternative to CloudFormation, you can use the [CLI or SDK to provision and manage a Resource Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-define-resource-servers.html#cognito-user-pools-define-resource-servers-cli-api). Using the SDK, you can create a [Lambda-Backed Customer Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) in your CloudFormation. Then you can add the Resource Server as a custom resource in your CloudFormation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/ab77/cfn-generic-custom-resource#cognito-demo) generic custom resource provider.

Use it like this (not tested, but should be almost working):

```
  ResourceServer:
    Type: 'Custom::CognitoResourceServer'
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !Sub '${CustomResourceLambdaArn}'
      AgentService: cognito-idp
      AgentType: client
      AgentCreateMethod: create_resource_server
      AgentUpdateMethod: update_resource_server
      AgentDeleteMethod: delete_resource_server
      AgentResourceId: Name
      AgentCreateArgs:
        UserPoolId: !Sub '${UserPool}'
        Name: 'my-resource-server'
        Identifier: 'https://foo.bar'
        Scopes:
        - ScopeName: 'my-scope'
        - ScopeDescription: 'My scope.'
      AgentUpdateArgs:
        UserPoolId: !Sub '${UserPool}'
        Name: 'my-resource-server'
        Identifier: 'https://foo.bar'
        Scopes:
        - ScopeName: 'my-scope'
        - ScopeDescription: 'My scope.'
      AgentDeleteArgs:
        Identifier: 'https://foo.bar'
```

> API [reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.create_resource_server).